# How to add a JSON-structure inside hashtable in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to put the information below as a hash table in Powershell. I think I need to add a hashtable inside a hashtable but I have no idea how to do that. can somebody help?

```
"credentials":{
  "add":{},
  "edit":{
    "58":{
      "username":"test",
      "auth_method":"Password",
      "password":"test"
    }
  },
  "delete":[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it absolutely have to be a hashtable? It looks like you've got some JSON there (missing a leading `{`).

In PowerShell v3 and higher, you can do this (note the fixed JSON string):

```powershell
$json = '{"credentials":{"add":{},"edit":{"58":{"username":"test","auth_method":"Password","password":"test"}},"delete":[]}}' 
$object = $json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now `$object` will be a `PSObject` with properties (as opposed to keys); very easy to work with.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. you are right, I am using json, i tried your method using convertfrom-json, however $object did not show any result. Here is the complete json request.

Comment: complete request  $jason = '{"uuid":"0625147c-30fe-d79f-e54f-ce7ccd7523e9b63d84cb81c23c2f","settings":{"name":"vivekkk cre"}, "credentials":{"add":{},"edit":{"58":{"username":"test1","auth_method":"Password","password":"test1"}}}}'


$show= convertfrom-json -InputObject $jason

Answer (score 0):

You could take help from syntax given below to create hash tables inside hash table in Powershell.

```
   $cred = @{

       1 = @{

          'x' = 'strin1';

          'y' = 'strin2'};

       2 = @{

          'y' = 'Strin3';

          'z' = 'Strin4' } 
}
```

The above code is self-explanatory( table $cred contains two tables inside it). Implementing this in your actual code is left for you to figure out.

Comment: Still not working as expected,  Here is what i did till now:    $data1= @{"uuid"="0625147c-30fe-d79f-e54f-ce7ccd7523e9b63d84cb81c23c2f"}
$settings=@{}
$settings.add("name","Windows Malware Scan5")
$settings.add("description","Windows Malware Scan5")
$data1.add("settings",$settings)
$credentials=@{}
$credentials.add = ("add", "")
$credentials.add = ("edit", $edit)
$edit=@{}
$edit.add= ("58",$uapd)
$uapd=@{}
$uapd.add("username","test1")
$uapd.add("auth_method","Password")
$uapd.add("password","test1")
$data1.add("credentials",$credentials)